# Elasticsearch URL prioritization in Searching

Tags: indexing, elasticsearch

I am currently working on a search infrastructure which uses elasticsearch as the indexing engine. The requirement is to crawl and index 5 subdomains:

- subdomain a is related to products
- subdomain b is related to FAQs/Questions
- subdomain c is related to internet plans

Now, once you search for anything related to products, it is required to prioritize searching in subdomain a -- that is, top results must belong to subdomain a. If one searches for questions, then top results must primarily come from subdomain b, and so on.

My idea is to separately index based on subdomain url, then give each some sort of priority using index.priority in elasticsearch. However, that proved to be unstable and still does not produce the desired effect.

Any other possible approaches you can suggest? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You should create indexes per subject so you can have transversal queries and use routing for separating groups of results.

Comment: so the idea is to separate groups of results. what is a transversal query?

Comment: Please refer to the elasticsearch documentation about routing and aliasing, you can use domain name as an attribute in your documents and create indexes per date, then each index will route your documents to each defined type, "products, faq" etc, then create aliases to filter the results as if they were indexes, https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/faking-it.html, that way you can do transversal queries by date.